# Android couldn't find "libsqlcipher_android.so"

Tags: android, sqlite

before writing this post, I looked around if anyone had my problem with the library SQLChiper.
As per the documentation I have included the files Jar properly and the ZIP file in the assets folder .
Now in the Activity, when initialize the database I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.app-2/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlcipher_android.so"
```

Helper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class DbCrypt extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "database.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static SQLiteDatabase db = null;


public DbCrypt(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    DbCrypt.db = db;



    ...


}
```

Activity

```
public class Add_category extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Button btnAddcat;
private ButtonRectangle btnAddField;
private TextView tvEmpty;
private ListView list;
private DbCrypt mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_category);


    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
    String pass = "9626";
    mDatabase = new DbCrypt(this);
...
}
```

I attach a picture[image]

gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/commons-codec.jar')
compile files('libs/guava-r09.jar')
compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
compile files('libs/sqlcipher-javadoc.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

}

Comment: It feels like your `build.gradle` file is not pulling that stuff in. You might wish to post your `app` module's `build.gradle` file. Instead of setting up SQLCipher for Android manually, you are welcome to use [my unofficial packaging of SQLCipher for Android as an artifact](https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-for-android-artifact), so you can pull it in through Gradle's dependency mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AndroidStudio please use AAR.
Download [AAR](https://bintray.com/version/files/bintray/jcenter/net.zetetic%3Aandroid-database-sqlcipher/3.3.1-2) file and include it to the libs folder in the project. Then add this to your build.gradle file - compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.3.1-2@aar'

Nothing else is needed. Only the .aar file. [More Information](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/implement-sqlcipher-in-to-a-app-with-few-modules/887)

Best of luck ...